# MongoDB is not responding with data in vercel deployment

Tags: deployment, vercel, next.js13

My API routes that query mongodb are responding with status 200 {} empty object, while other routes that do not engage with mongodb are responding in a proper way, meaning are returning what is specified in route response body.

This is my mongodb query:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGEdJ.png)

This is my generic, normal query:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wYAZ.png)

This is my vercel.json file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J497i.png)

It is important to note, that mongodb queries are all working perfectly fine in developement mode. But when i deploy the site to vercel, its acting this way. I do have my MONGODB_URI included in the vercel .env's on the dashboard settings, the same as i have in my local environment.

I dont know whats wrong, this is the simplest project there could ever be, and still its performing  horribly.